# Object literal jquery event scoping

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to solve this scoping problem?

```
NAMESPACE.myObject = {
  foo: 'foo',
  init: function() {
    $('.myBtn').on('click', this.myMethod);
  },
  myMethod: function() {
    console.log($(this), foo);
  }
};
NAMESPACE.myObject.init();
```

The result of the console.log should be the jQuery object that was clicked and the propertie foo of myObject. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you can't have more than one `this`, so need to work around it.

As a general rule, create a scoped variable (`THIS` in the example below) to hold the scope you want to retain/access from inside any other scope.

You need to retain the `this` on the call to the myMethod though, inside the click handler, so you can't just pass `myMethod` as it loses the `myObject` instance.

```
NAMESPACE.myObject = {
  this.foo: 'foo',
  init: function() {
    var THIS = this;
    $('.myBtn').on('click', function(){
        // "this" here is the button clicked
        // "THIS" is still the myObject instance
        THIS.myMethod(this);
    });
  },
  myMethod: function(element) {
    // "this" here is myObject
    // The clicked element was passed as parameter "element" instead
    console.log($(element), this.foo);
  }
};
NAMESPACE.myObject.init();
```

I hope I explained *this* clearly enough :)

As jfriend00 points out, you can also use `bind` to basically create a function call with `this` scope on-the-fly (very cute), but that does not work on IE8 or older.

Comment: Best answer, Good support and also keeps a reference to the element that was clicked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.bind()` like this:

```
NAMESPACE.myObject = {
  foo: 'foo',
  init: function() {
    $('.myBtn').on('click', this.myMethod.bind(this));
  },
  myMethod: function() {
    console.log($(this), foo);
  }
};
NAMESPACE.myObject.init();
```

Or, for older versions of IE, since you already have jQuery you can use jQuery's `$.proxy()`:

```
NAMESPACE.myObject = {
  foo: 'foo',
  init: function() {
    $('.myBtn').on('click', $.proxy(this.myMethod, this));
  },
  myMethod: function() {
    console.log($(this), foo);
  }
};
NAMESPACE.myObject.init();
```

When you pass `this.myMethod` to the event listener, it loses its binding to `this` (as you've noticed) because the event listener doesn't save that reference or call the method with it.  One way to keep that binding is to use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (requires IE9 or a polyfill for earlier versions of IE).

Comment: That's cool. Did not know you could do that :) Will have to investigate bind further... Investigated: no support for IE 8 and older.. that's why they never use it here :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie `$.proxy` does the same thing, and works in IE8

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - if you already have jQuery (which you do apparently), you can use `$.proxy()` or you can add the polyfill on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) which make it work in all browser versions.  Info on `$.proxy` added to my answer.

Comment: With this solution you don't know which element was clicked right?

Comment: @user1081577 - the `event` object is still passed to the callback so you can still look at `event.target` to see what object generated the event.  You would probably want to declare that as the first argument to `myMethod` or you can access it as `arguments[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Since I see you tagged jQuery, you can also use this approach, I know it is different from what you posted in the question, but I still an option.

[**working example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LjDiJ)

```
var NAMESPACE = NAMESPACE || {};  

$(function() {
    "use strict"
    $.extend(NAMESPACE, true, {
        getMyObject: function() {
             function myObject() {
                var self = this;
                self.foo = 'foo';
                self.init = function() {
                                $('.myBtn').click(self.myMethod); 
                };
                self.myMethod = function() {
                                console.log($(this), self.foo);
                };
            }
            return new myObject(); 
        }
    }); 

    var myObject = NAMESPACE.getMyObject();
    myObject.init();
})
```

Comment: This is one of the few cases where switching to jQuery *actually increased* the amount of code :) Kind of defeats the "more for less" approach of jQuery :) Does work though.

Comment: Well this way your code is a little more structured. the only jquery bits is the ready function and $.extend that helps with namespacing, plus "use strict"

Comment: also it is not object literal so you can create as many instances of myObject as you want...

Comment: This is a cool alternative solution. But its a lot more code and a literal object is good for the problem i'm facing